# Как скрыть label при нажатии на любую область окна программы? JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При нажатии на label1(желтая) появляются label2, label3(розовые). Как сделать на JavaFX чтобы при клики на любую область окна программы (серую) label2 и label3 исчезали?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Могу предположить, что серая - это какая-то [Pane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Pane.html). Значит можно повесить обработчик на эту `pane` и скрывать 2 и 3 лайблы

```
pane.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, event - > {
    label2.setVisible(false);
    label3.setVisible(false);
});
```

Comment: root.setOnMouseClicked((MouseEvent e)->{ ... });

Comment: а root - это что такое?

Comment: root, обычно - это корневой элемент, передаваемый в конструктор сцены. Например `Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1200, 900);`, где root может быть VBox, Group или ещё какой Node.